# Switching to Angular Universal with external API Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

First of all, thanks for taking a look at my question!

I have built my project on server-side(Nodejs) and client-side(Angular6).

The app functionality is just giving all kinds of crypto-currency price and information.

I am trying to switch my angular project to Angular Universal Server Side Rendering due to SEO, and having difficulty in making decisions and move on to the project.

So I am trying to implement Angular-universal on my pre-existing nodejs server,

1. Is there way, not switching to typescript server, and just use angular-universal on my pre-existing node server? is there any documentation or recommendation for me to implement?
2. Is there another way of SEO, so that when I search bitcoin, my angular website's bitcoin information gets showed in google?

I have followed all kinds of steps switching to angular universal and changing server.ts file to my server.js file and realized that if I implement universal angular, I only have one package.json file serving both server.ts and angular project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are not forced to use typescript, you could modify your existing nodejs server to listen for universal requests as well (in plain js)

**Edit**

I just realised you were talking about your nodejs server for the API only, not as an existing webserver for your frontend. You can still only have one server, but it's probably better to separate the 2

2. Google can already crawl angular websites (up to a certain point), without universal. But using universal will improve your website's speed, so you'll be more likely to have a better ranking in search results

Comment: Thanks for reply! I understand what you suggested. However, maybe I don't quite understand how Angular Universal works. As you said, I can modify my existing nodejs server to listen fro universal request, then do I have two servers? one with angular universal on :4000, and my own API server on :3000?

Comment: Yes. And are you using nginx or another webserver as a reverse proxy?